# How to filter based on the model's another foreign key's properties

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am developing an algorithm to match appointment requests and create appointments. Relevant models to the question

```
Slot:
    day (enum, 0-6)
    start_time
    end_time

User:
    available_slots (day)

AppointmentRequest:
    user
    week_starting (monday's date)

Appointment:
    users
    week_starting
    slot (monday's date)
```

There are a lot of criteria and the number of requests is quite few, so weekly looping thorough appointment_requests seemed a reasonable choice:

```
for appointment_request in appointment_requests:

    user_appointment_slots = Appointment.objects.filter(Q(week_starting=appointment_request.weel    ) &
                                                       (Q(first_user=appointment_request.user) |
                                                        Q(second_user=appointment_request.user))).slot_set.all()

    user_available_slots = appointment_request.user.available_slots_set.all() \
                .exclude(pk__in=user_appointment_slots)


    potential_requests = appointment_requests \
                .filter(user__available_slots__id__in=user_available_slots) \
                .exclude(user=appointment_request.user)
```

However, when filtering `appointment_requests` to create `potential_requests`, I need to exclude `potential_requests`' users' available slots that are already filled with another `Appointment` objects. I believe I need something like:

```
.exclude(user__available_slots__pk__in=<what_to_put_here>)
```

Basically, `<what_to_put_here>` should give me that object's (of type `AppointmentRequest`), `User`'s `Appointment`s' slots. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: .exclude(user__available_slots__pk__in=user.appointment.slots.values_list.filter('pk', flat=True))

Comment: @AndreyShipilov I don't have a user object in context. I am trying to filter based on the users of the AppointmentRequest's that I am querying.